# Blazor data-bind dynamically generated elements

Tags: blazor

I want to dynamically create and bind some `select` elements from a list of "AdditionalFields" on my Blazor web page.

I need to bind each element to the `CheckoutData` variable.

But I don't know how I can create a variable / Array, or something like it, that is correctly updated via bind-value.

For more details you can view my attached ([Image](https://ibb.co/DDf8HjX)) and this source code:

```
@if (StoreData.StoreContainer?.AdditionalFields != null)
    @foreach (var additionalField in     StoreData.StoreContainer.AdditionalFields)
    {
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="page_input">
                <label> @additionalField.Caption </label>
                <InputSelect class="checkout-control pristine untouched" @bind-Value="@CheckoutData.OrderTimeType">
                    @foreach (var keyValue in additionalField.ValueList)
                    {
                        <option value="@keyValue.Sort" selected="@(keyValue == additionalField.ValueList[0] ? "selected" : "")">@keyValue.SelectionText</option>
                    }
                </InputSelect>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is? Are you trying to say that `CheckoutData.OrderTimeType` isn't being updated to the currently selected value in the drop down list?

Comment: No, that variable is wrong (was copy pasted)
Just want to have variables in the checkout class, that will bei filled / bound to the List of additionalFields correctly and don't know how to do this right now and here...

Comment: Can you clarify what type the AdditionalFields property is?

Comment: AdditionalFields are List of simple class with Caption (string) and ValueList (List of ValueMembers for that AdditionalField with Sort and SelectionText).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a sample [BlazorFiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/jkcovolc) that shows how you can handle selection of the elements within a list of `AdditionalFields`, roughly as per your example in the question.

To show a selection I added a `.Selected` property to the `AdditionalField` class but you might be storing this elsewhere.

#### Key points to note:

```cs
    int count = additionalFields.Count;
    for (var i=0; i < count; i++)
    {
        int current = i; // don't use loop variable in binding
        var additionalField = additionalFields[current];
```

I used a `for` loop to iterate through the `AdditionalFields` and saved the current index within the loop - this is important to ensure you don't pass the loop variable in the `@onchanged` event handler. I didn't use `bind` here so it's easy to see what happens.

```html
                <select class="checkout-control pristine untouched" @onchange="((e) => HandleSelect(e, current))" >
```

I used a HTML select instead of the `InputSelect`, and handle the `@onchange` event: this passes the event arguments `e` and the current index to the `HandleSelect` method

You'll probably need to adapt this approach but it shows one way you can dynamically bind in Blazor.

**Important note**: the code sets the `Selected` value of the second field to the second sort value to demonstrate the `selected` attribute is working correctly.

**However**, note that the first field shows "sort 1" as selected but does NOT fire an event - this is HTML auto-selecting the first element in the select list, so the first element's `Selected` property would still be null. Either ensure the Selected is set at the start, e.g. to the first value, or have a blank `<option value="">[select a sort]</option>` as the first item which will bind to the blank select.